# How to write redux selector that handle several levels of nested state?

Tags: reactjs, redux, state, derived

I would like my container component to be as much reusable as it can be. To achieve that, I want to write reusable selector to use it in `mapStateToProps` function. I know that this function can accept props of the current component, so I can pass dynamic state key to my selector `getAllEntities`. The problem appears, when I want from my selector to get first level of state, but in other place - to get some nested state.

Demonstration of state shape:

```
{
  items: { byId: { ... }, allIds: { ... } }
  comparison: {
    otherItems: { byId: { ... }, allIds: { ... } }
    // and so on
  }
}
```

Selector demonstration:

```
getAllEntities = (state) => state.allIds.map(id => state.byId[id]);
```

And I use it in my component's `mapStateToProps` function:

```
return { items: getAllEntities(state[ownProps.stateKey]) }
```

The problem with my approach is that it seems that (by keeping reusability of this component) I can only access first level of state. So I cannot pass props to my component that will understand that it should look for `state.comparison.otherItems` - watch state shape demonstration above.

I tried something like:

```
getAllEntities = (state, key1) => {
  if (has(state, key1) {
    return state[key1].allIds.map(id => state[key1].byId[id]);
  }

  return state.allIds.map(id => state.byId[id]);
}
```

So if I pass `key1` string - it should look deeper in state. If `key1` is not passed to component's props - then behave normally and look for first level of state shape.

I don't even know if it's the correct approach... Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: Do you need one selector for both cases, with key and without? Maybe you can do two selector, one for root state, one for state in key. If not - your approach looks ok to my mind

Comment: Hi @iofjuupasli! I think only one selector is a must to keep my component reusable. Otherwise I end up making multiple, the same looking and working components - the only difference between them is `mapStateToProps` function - the selector I use...

Answer (score 1):

You can recursively reuse selector:

```
getAllEntities = (state, key1) => {
  if (has(state, key1) {
    return getAllEntities(state[key1])
  }

  return state.allIds.map(id => state.byId[id]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @iofjuupasli, that's nice solution. Also, as agreed on discord redux community, it's just better to write two selectors. Then to avoid much code duplication, write something like:

```
const SomeComponent = () => {};

const WithSomeDataSource = connect(doOneThingHere)(SomeComponent);
const WithAnotherDataSource = connect(doSomethingElseHere)(SomeComponent);
```